# Dropping an object in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I want my code to resemble the following graph below in which an individual drops an object on the ground. The graph resembles one object of the many objects an individual will drop in the z dimension. Initial velocity is 10 and initial distance is 0. Gravity is 9.81. For now, we will just use this object. Velocity has to be set before the location. My code isn't returning the correct output.

Here is my Scala Code

```
class PhysicsVector(val x: Double, val y: Double, val z: Double){
}


class PhysicalObject(var location: PhysicsVector, var velocity: PhysicsVector){
}

class World(var gravity:Double){
var objects: List[PhysicalObject] = List()
}

object Physics {
def updateWorld(earth: World, deltaTime: Double): Unit = {
    val initial = 10.0
    for (i<-earth.objects){
    val zVelocity = -(initial-(earth.gravity*deltaTime))
    val d = 0
    i.velocity = new PhysicsVector(0.0, 0.0, zVelocity)
    i.location = new PhysicsVector(0.0, 0.0 , d + (zVelocity * deltaTime))
    }
}
}
```

Here is the graph with the formula
[Resemble this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0lUS.png)

Answer (score 1):

This code sets the location and velocity to the same value for every object and for every call, because all your computations are based on constants. You need to read the current velocity and location from the object and modify them.